# How to convert binary file to Nifti?

Tags: python, medical-imaging

We are sending data from a webpage to a python server with Json and we are trying to make predictions on the medical images. The images are supposed to be saved in .bin format. Would it be possible to convert the binary files into .nii?

Comment: This library likely has the functionality you need -- http://niftilib.sourceforge.net/pynifti/intro.html